# How to highlight a Datagridview row and un-highlight on button click

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm using c# in datagridview.

How can I highlight a row until I decide to un-highlight it on button click? Kind of like just placing an indication on a row that can be placed/removed anytime.

Comment: Have you checked the datagridview documentation for anything like this?

Comment: i havent, what is datagridview documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a CellMouseMove Event and using the following line of code to change the color.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{    
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

To change it back after clicking, also add a CellMouseClick event and instead of changing it to Color.Yellow, use the same line of code but with Color.White

Hope that helps!

Comment: how do i add a cellmouseclick event?

Comment: In the design window for your program left click the control and the properties will appear. At the top of the properties tab is a lightning bolt that says "Events". Double-click the CellMouseClick event and Visual Studio will automatically add the necessary code. It'll look like this https://i.gyazo.com/429b0d9389f97a1900acab8ede681688.png